# How do I access outer class instance attributes from an inner class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How do I make a class like this?

```py
>>> model = Model(x=3, y=5)
>>> data = model.Data(y=7)
>>> data.x
3
>>> data.y
7
```

Essentially, the Data class should be able to access model's instance attributes whilst allowing overrides. I assume it's a special kind of inner class?

My Attempt:

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y

    class Data:
        def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
```

Comment: Please update your question with some of your attempts at writing this class.

Comment: @quamrana added my attempt, though it's not working obviously

Comment: There's no such thing as an "inner class" in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking more of using `collections.namedtuple`:

```py
from collections import namedtuple  #collections.namedtuple
from copy import deepcopy

class Model:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.params = kwargs
        self.DataType = namedtuple('Data', self.params.keys())
    
    def Data(self, **kwargs):
        d = deepcopy(self.params)
        d.update(kwargs)
        return self.DataType(**d)

model = Model(x=3, y=5)
data = model.Data(y=7)
print(data, data.x, data.y)
```

Output as expected.

Comment: is there a way to do that without violating PEP8? If there isn't that's also fine